# How to specify the required Key value paid when calling the AWS Textract API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ocr, key-value, text-extraction, amazon-textract

Does Textract have pre-defined key-value pairs or is it possible to define "key value pairs".

e.g. It can extract key value pairs like Name. But can I ask it to get the same for a new key say "ABCD"?

If yes how to do the same?

Comment: Read the documentation or just try out the demo that AWS has provided for Textract. It gives you a map of the key value pairs, their relationships with other entities and their position on the document.

Comment: I couldnt find it in the documentation where it tells hwo to create "new" key value pairs or what are the pre-trained key value pairs already available

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by new key value pairs. If it detects name and address it will return name and address in the json. You can check the response json in their demo.

Comment: what i meant is the current model can read key value pairs like "Name", "Address", etc. Two questions here:
1. How to know which value pairs is the model trained for (List of the same)
2. How to specify or add more KVP?

Comment: It is trained to detect all key value pairs. It will recognize the key and value associated with it doesn't matter what the name of the key is. If your form element is called "ABCD" it will detect it. You don't need to specify anything. Also, if you just need to extract form data in regular forms, you can do it faster and more accurately by just writing a python script for it without using textract. Only use textract if you need to perform OCR on the PDF.